# Проблема с Gradle при установке Android Studio в оффлайн режиме

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Установил portable версию Android Studio на свой рабочий ПК, на котором нет выхода в интернет. При открытии проекта сразу же выскакивает проблема с Gradle - `Gradle project sync failed`.

Полностью ошибка выглядит так:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0 available for offline mode.

Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

Насколько я понял из лога ошибки `No cached version of...`, дело в том, что в файле `build.gradle` находятся ссылки, к которым, естественно, без интернета доступа нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему? Возможно, надо вставить в build.gradle не адрес в интернете, а найти нужные файлы, скачать и разместить в build.gradle путь к ним?
Всё происходит в оффлайн режиме Gradle.

Сам build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google/com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google/com'
        } // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: У вас нет закешированной версии gradle, один раз ему нужно дать интернет - что бы он закешировал его.

Comment: Возможности нет, к сожалению, доступ в интернет заблокирован.

Comment: https://coderoad.ru/28359851/как-установить-android-studio-full-offline#28647847